# Viewbox placement in referencing SVG symbols and CSS dimensions

Tags: css, svg, browser

*I edited my initial cry of despair into something more to the technical point, in order to turn it into a Q&A.*

I'm using SVG symbols that I reference in the document with `use` elements. I'm styling these with CSS. I don't want to set both height and width in the CSS, I want to set only one of them with the other one scaling accordingly.

I do set a `viewBox` attribute on the symbol. But the graphic does not scale correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SVG Symbols</title>
    <style>
     body { margin: 20px; }
     .svg-large { width: 500px; fill: yellow;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg style="display:none;">
      <symbol id="scary-smiley" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
 <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9.5" stroke-width="1"
  stroke="black" />
 <circle cx="6" cy="7" r="1.5" fill="black"/>
 <circle cx="14" cy="7" r="1.5" fill="black"/>
 <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Teeth_by_David_Shankbone.jpg/320px-Teeth_by_David_Shankbone.jpg"
        width="10" height="5.2" x="5" y="11"/>
      </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg class="svg-large">
      <use xlink:href="#scary-smiley"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even weirder: Scaling down from the SVG's size, e.g. changing the CSS to `.icon { height: 50px; }` _does_ have the intended effect in all browsers. Is it possible that both Chrome and Firefox might show the same bug?

Comment: This is because the default `width` of an `<svg>` is `300`, and that your firsts examples fit in 300x400 ratio, while yours doesn't. (the default height being 150, but you did change it through CSS.) Set `.icon{width: 400px;}` and yours will be fine too, or set their own viewBox.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you! Yeah, I just about now figured this out myself. I started to edit my question before I saw your comment. I think I need to walk away from the computer for a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The code below has been tested in current Firefox, Chrome and a Webkit-based browser named Midori.*

For some reason, defining the `viewBox` on the `symbol` element does not have the full desired effect in Firefox and Chrome. It does have *some* effect, though, as it makes the element scaleable. So, if you want set both `width` *and* `height` in CSS, you can do that.

If the `viewBox` element is specified only on the `symbol` and you set only one of `width` or `height`, then in Firefox and Chrome the other dimension is set according the default object size in HTML 5 whis is 300x150 px. So, in the example in the question, you get a 500x150 px element and the graphic is scaled to fit that rectangle.

If you want to define only one `width` or `height` with the other one scaling accordingly, then defining `viewBox` on the *referencing* SVG element works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SVG Symbols</title>
    <style>
     body { margin: 20px; }
     .svg-large { width: 500px; fill: yellow;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <svg style="display:none;">
      <symbol id="scary-smiley">
 <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9.5" stroke-width="1"
  stroke="black" />
 <circle cx="6" cy="7" r="1.5" fill="black"/>
 <circle cx="14" cy="7" r="1.5" fill="black"/>
 <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Teeth_by_David_Shankbone.jpg/320px-Teeth_by_David_Shankbone.jpg"
        width="10" height="5.2" x="5" y="11"/>
      </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg class="svg-large" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <use xlink:href="#scary-smiley"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Firefox' and Chrome's behaviour is standard compliant, [according to the SVG 2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#EstablishingANewSVGViewport), according to which the `<svg><use .../></svg>` clause establishes a new SVG viewport.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Thank you! I edited the answer. I hope I got it right this time.